# How should we set up distribution of iOS app to allow regression testing in future?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, software-distribution, regression-testing

We do all of our iOS app beta and normal distribution through iTunesConnect.  However, there are times that we want to install an older version of our app on a device so that we can test a database migration or older API communication.

Older versions on iTunesConnect expire after 60 days, but we may want to install a version several months old.

Do we have to set up a parallel distribution of our app to Fabric so we can go back to the previous versions?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

If you use git, you can create a tag at the commit that is the one that was released as version x.
Next time you want to install it, you can checkout that tag, and run it on your device. If you need people installing it without Xcode, you have to create n (internal) website where your testers can download the .ipa and install it on their i-devices.